# Can one brute force entries to create the whole file?

Tags: hash

I want to know if one can brute-force a large list of entries (>10,00,000) in linear time to form a whole file.
For example:

 I have an ebook and i extract all the words and symbols from that ebook.

 Then I count the frequency of all words and symbols.

 Then I get the binary representation of file and I hash it with SHA256.

 Then I will create a program that take the frequency of all symbols and words to form meaningful sentences from it (a kind of brute-force with grammatical expressions as inputs).

 Then I will hash every possible structure generated by the program to find one which matches the hash of the original file.

 So, will this kind of brute-force be any better (faster) than the brute-force with just a hash.

 A normal brute-force may involve:

 Brute-forcing all permutaions of all n bit binary segments, which formed the ebook. 
Problem is: 
1.That it is not possible to brute-force these segments in less time (May require more time than the current age of the universe).

 2. Computing power to complete this task is way more than what quantum computers have today.

 3. Rate of Collision is very high when one is mapping a larger set of entries to a smaller one.

So, I think brute-forcing with english words with grammatical restrictions (how sentences are formed as the word is more likely to be 'I have' and not 'I me') will require way less computing power and time as opposed to a normal brute-force which may have n! or 2^n permutations (2^n ,in case of binary).
Is this method as inefficient as normal brute-force attack (or worst) ?

 Note:

 Sample space is the set of english words such as the, are, I etc.

 Will this kind of brute-force take months if not years ?

 Will it really generate way less files (as grammatical restrictions are there) as opposed to a n MB file which is made up of n bytes hence will have 2^n permutations ?

 Is this as impractical as brute forcing a file with just a hash ?

 Will Dynamic programming be any helpful in this task ?

Comment: Not months or years, but lifetime of the universe. There is an estimate that due to the laws of physics, the upper limit for any algorithm is 2^256 state changes.

Comment: You are overusing **bold text**. It seems you are virtually shouting at us, it's just distracting and makes the text harder to read.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden sorry, I thought it would be helpful for attracting attention toward certain text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There have been many estimates of the entropy of the English language, ranging (depending on how you define it, how you measure it, and which corpus you use) between slightly less than 1 bit per character to close to 5 bits per character.

This means that even a very short text such as your question already has between 1500 and 7500 bits of entropy.

Even if we assume only 0.5 bits per character, then a 512 character long text will already have more entropy than the resulting hash. Which means even this short answer already has more entropy than the resulting hash.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but can you please elaborate more as I don't know much about Entropy. And as per your answer will this kind of brute-forcing be practical ?

Comment: Akash, “entropy” is something you will have to learn about yourself. Out of interest, lookup “second law of thermodynamics”.